# ClosureCompiler: create_name_map_files from Java API

Tags: java, closures, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

from command-line i can get a alias list of the function renaming from compiler.jar

Help says:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --help
[...]
--create_name_map_files                : If true, variable renaming and
                                         property renaming map files will be
                                         produced as {binary name}_vars_map.out
                                         and {binary name}_props_map.out. Note
                                         that this flag cannot be used in
                                         conjunction with either variableMapOut
                                         putFile or property_map_output_file
--create_source_map VAL                : If specified, a source map file
                                         mapping the generated source files
                                         back to the original source file will
                                         be output to the specified path. The
                                         %outname% placeholder will expand to
                                         the name of the output file that the
                                         source map corresponds to.
[...]
```

so, how can i get "create_name_map_files" from inline java? i took a look into the AbstractCommandLineRunner.java but all classes/methods which relate to this command line option are private and not reachable from my code..

My Code:

```
CompilerOptions opt = new CompilerOptions();

// decide mode
compilationLevel.ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS.setOptionsForCompilationLevel(opt);
opt.prettyPrint = false;

Compiler.setLoggingLevel(Level.OFF);

Compiler compressor = new Compiler();
compressor.disableThreads();

List<SourceFile> inputs = ...;
List<SourceFile> externs = ...;

compressor.compile(externs, inputs, opt);
```

Comment: CommandLineRunner.java got an description in the header to do this.. but maybe someone knows more..

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the option : variable_map_output_file filename , similarly for props.

Note that: The flags variable_map_output_file and create_name_map_files cannot both be used simultaniously.

Answer (score 0):

From [`CommandLineRunner.java`](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner.java?spec=svn1dce5f689387f67cb10ad73964d2a46345504c49&r=1dce5f689387f67cb10ad73964d2a46345504c49#781), I would say

```
opt.setCreateNameMapFiles(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "compile" function returns a Result object that contains the variable (variableMap) and property (propertyMap) renaming maps.  These properties contain VariableMap objects that can be serialized:

```
Result result = compiler.compiler(...);
result.variableMap.save(varmapPath);
result.propertyMap.save(propmapPath);
```